# Different query results returned in Coldfusion versions

Tags: datetime, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10

We are running a cfquery on two different versions of ColdFusion (CF9 and CF10).  When the results are returned the dates are formatted differently in the separate versions.

The Query is

```
SELECT TOP 100 CONVERT(DATE,Field1,121),Field2
FROM A_TABLE
```

In CF9 the return for Field 1 looks like `2010-06-01`.

In Cf10 the the return for Field 1 looks like `{ts '2010-06-01 00:00:00'}`

Has anyone else notice this difference?  We have searched the CF documentation and haven't noticed any mention of this change.

Comment: It's all the same if you use DateFormat function.

Comment: How is it that you are viewing this data?

Comment: It appears that on CF9, ColdFusion was not returning the format advertised in the Microsoft documentation, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx.

Comment: I am viewing this data by doing a cfdump.  But the format carries through to other outputs as well including serializeJson

Comment: Whenever you need a formatted date/time, use `dateFormat()`, `timeFormat()` and/or (in Cf 10) `dateTimeFormat()` - see my answer below.

Comment: @DanBracuk : The linked page indicates that the format should be: ODBC canonical (with milliseconds) yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm(24h) . I am not seeing ms, but it does seem closer

Answer (score 6):

The data being returned is the same. What you are seeing in CF10 is the way ColdFusion displays date/time objects. (edited based on feedback from Miguel-F)

Whenever you are outputting dates/times, you can (and should) use `dateFormat()` , `timeformat()` (and in CF 10 `datetimeformat()` ) to format the dates/times in a standard way.

Comment: _What you are seeing in CF10 is the way ColdFsuion displays 'raw' dates/times form a database_ - I don't believe this is accurate. The difference is in CF10 it appears to be returning a date/time object and in CF9 it appears to just return a string representation. The output `{ts '2010-06-01 00:00:00'}` is how ColdFusion displays date/time objects.

Comment: Maybe it is a difference in the JDBC driver. Either way `dateFormat()`, `timeFormat()` and/or `dateTimeFormat()` will solve any display issues he is having.

Comment: I edited answer to take into account what you pointed out @Miguel-F

Comment: Yes I agree with you. Just trying to point out that it looks like CF10 is actually returning a date/time object

Comment: @Miguel-F : Technically `CONVERT(DATE, ...)` *should* return a `java.sql.Date` object in both versions. It is just a matter of how CF chooses to display it. CF9 must use [`Date.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toString%28%29), which explains why the result is "yyyy-mm-dd". My guess is that CF10 either displays `java.sql.Date`'s differently -OR- possibly the query is returning a `Timestamp` object instead. You would have to dump the query column class to know for sure ie `#queryName.field1[1].getClass().name#`.

Comment: (Edit) @Tim - That said, do not trust things like `cfdump`. It is really only for debugging and favors ["human-friendly" representation over precision](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586356/scientific-notation-with-precisionevaluate-in-coldfusion/18594912#18594912). As Scott said, the way to ensure a consistent format is to use `date/time/dateTimeFormat()`.

Comment: @Leigh I did the dump you talked about on the column and you are correct CF10 returns java.sql.Date  CF9 returns java.lang.String

Comment: @TimBrown ColdFusion can still treat the string as a date though. The solution is that whenever you want to output dates - even as part of a JSON object - use `dateFormat()`, `timeFormat()` or `dateTimeFormat()`

Comment: @ScottStroz  Problem with using DateFormat is I can not set the column in the query to YYYY-MM-DD becasue the DataType of the column is java.sql.date and even after applying the change it goes back the data type of **{ts '2010-06-01 00:00:00'}**

Comment: *I can not set the column in the query* @TimBrown - I do not quite follow you. You should only use formatting functions for presentation. Can you update your question to show us an example of how you are using it, and the issue it is causing?

Comment: This data is getting sent directly as a query object to Serialize JSON so there is no way to format for presentation before it is passed to SerialzeJSON

Comment: Oh, if `serializeJSON` is doing some sort of auto-conversion with datetime columns you may need to a) cast/convert the values to a string within the SQL OR b) add a `varchar column` to the query object, then loop through it and populate the *varchar* column manually with `dateFormat()`.

Comment: `serializeJSON()` may be formatting the data based on the data type of the query column. You can also use `CAST` or `CONVERT` to format the date directly from the database. Here is a good reference - http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx