# What is the return type of an object created with CreateODBCDateTime()?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

Say I have the following function in cfscript... what would the return type be?

```
[return type goes here] function GetODBCDateTime () {

    return CreateODBCDateTime (Now ());

}
```

HINT: It's not `ODBCDateTime`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short Answer:** Take a look at the [documentation for cffunction](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-f/cffunction.html), which shows the available return types. For date and time objects use `date`, *not* string. Though unless there is a specific reason you need CreateODBCDateTime, you can simply use `Now()` instead. For *most* purposes the two are equivalent.

**Longer Answer:**

> *A date-time object, in ODBC timestamp format*
>
> which really means: a string in ODBC timestamp format.

Not exactly. Though it does have a very specific format when *represented* as a string, CreateODBCDateTime still returns a date/time object. If you dump the class information, you can see it is actually a subclass of [java.util.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), rather than java.lang.String.

```
 // string representation
 writeDump(GetODBCDateTime().toString());
 // base class
 writeDump(GetODBCDateTime().getClass().name);
 // superclass
 writeDump(GetODBCDateTime().getClass().getSuperClass().name);
```

> For example, I can call getClass().getSuperClass().name on the returned object and get java.util.Date, if the return type is either date or string!

You are right, but that should not happen IMO. I do not know how CF handles return types internally, but ... it sounds like this is either due to CF's usual [automagic-type-conversion](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/the-cfml-programming-language/using-coldfusion-variables/data-type-conversion.html) rules at work -OR- perhaps CF simply uses the return type to verify an object *can* be converted to the specified type and if so, the object is returned "as is". However, you should still use type `date` to ensure the function *always* returns a date object. Otherwise, it could return anything it wants, like the string "apple" instead of a date.

> Dumping either returned object always gives a plain text string.

Now that *is* what I would expect. When you cfdump any object, CF typically invokes the object's [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString) method. As the name implies, it returns a string representation of the object. With CreateODBCDateTime, toString() is designed to return the underlying date value in a very specific format of `{ts 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:nn:ss'}`. However, internally the object is still a date. Yet when dumped, it is visually identical to a date string with the same value.  (Dumps are great for debugging, but [they favor presentation over accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586356/scientific-notation-with-precisionevaluate-in-coldfusion), so do not always trust what you see ;-).

Comment: Thanks for a thoughtful answer. Whether I set the return type to `string` or `date`, the actual thing returned appears to have possibly identical propertes. For example, I can call `getClass().getSuperClass().name` on the returned object and get `java.util.Date`, if the return type is either `date` or `string`! Dumping either returned object always gives a plain text string.

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6deb.html), looks like a DateTime structured in ODBC timestamp format.

Comment: A string or a numeric representation perhaps? _When passing a date/time object as a string, enclose it in quotation marks. Otherwise, it is interpreted as a numeric representation of a date/time object._ from http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7ff4.html

Comment: I noticed that, but thanks for taking your time to try and help.

Answer (score 0):

A correct answer appears to be `string`. I guess it's important to remember that strings are considered objects in ColdFusion (and Java). From the docs, the return type of `CreateODBCDateTime()` is:

> A date-time **object**, in ODBC timestamp format.

which can be  a **string** in ODBC timestamp format, in this case.