# Coldfusion number format

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have a code like this :

```
 <cfset n = '222222222222222'>
 <cfset sum=0>
 <cfset sum +=  n>
<cfoutput>#sum#</cfoutput>
```

The output is :

```
2.22222222222E+014
```

Is there any way I can get output in normal form as '222222222222222' ?

Comment: But "222222222222222" would be so difficult to read because there's so many numbers. With exponential notation you can immediately see the magnitude of the number.

Comment: Yes, But for now the exponential form is causing problem for me :) , so I was looking for a work around but didn't found any thing relevant on web.

Comment: What kind of problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value of n is 222222222222222. It's a big integer. To perform arithmatic operation on big integer, you need [precision evaluate function](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fd9.html).
Your code should be as below:

```
<cfset n = '222222222222222'>
<cfset sum=0>
<cfset sum = precisionEvaluate(sum + n)>
<cfoutput>#sum#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: It is needed to maintain precision, yes. However, that does not mean the output will *never* contain scientific notation. While not applicable in this specific case, even using BigDecimal, [some numbers may still be displayed with scientific notation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18594912/104223), fyi.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution (works with the given example): [CF Doc - NumberFormat](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-72c8.html)

`#NumberFormat(sum, '9')#`

Comment: While not applicable in this case, keep in mind values may be rounded. See [numberFormat / usage](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-72c8.html) for more details.